# SAML Request with multiple AuthnContextClassRef and Response that indicates status of each

Tags: saml

Consider that I have an n-factor authentication:

> saml:AuthnContextClassRef
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password ...
>   saml:AuthnContextClassRef urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:TimesyncToken

How do I indicate the result of each in the Response?
Do I need an assertion for each?  I don't want to rely on the single StatusCode to indicate a net result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ⚠️ **Warning: this answer is wrong** despite being the accepted answer
>
> As noted in the comments, a Response can only have one
> AuthnContextClassRef element.
> One would
> have to include a `AuthnContextDecl` nested element with a value(s)
> that is agreed between SP and IDP. Thanks @Patrick

You can include multiple `AuthnContextClassRef` elements in the SAML Response as part of the `AuthnStatement` in the `Assertion`, e.g.:

```
<AuthnContext>
    <AuthnContextClassRef>
        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
    </AuthnContextClassRef>
    <AuthnContextClassRef>
        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:TimesyncToken
    </AuthnContextClassRef>
</AuthnContext>
```

Those represents the "context" wrt. the authentication event. If some factors are optional, you would only include the ones that succeeded and leave out ones that did not succeed or were not triggered.

The `StatusCode` is actually independent of that, indicating overall authentication success/failure.

Comment: Right, but lets say that for password, the correct password was given, so that auth mechanism succeeded.   And for TimesyncToken, the WRONG token was given so that mechanism failed.  How do I indicate which one failed and which one succeeded?

Comment: I edited the answer at about the time that you asked the question ;-) you would not include factors that did not succeed. If it was a requirement that they both succeeded, the overall `StatusCode` would indicate failure.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think multiple `AuthnContextClassRef` in a `AuthnContext` is valid. It is fine during the request but not the response. According to the [spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) (line 1146)  there can be only 1 (no  `maxOccurs="unbounded"` is defined). Also Scott Cantor (the spec editor and maintainer of Shibboleth) says as much on the shib mailing list: "SAML does not permit a single AuthnStatement to have multiple AuthnContextClassRefs"